# php send two button's value on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I'm working on a hospital's system.

The records come from an array.
I want to send the values from my two buttons to another page.

For instance, in the first page:

```
1   xyz First   2017-04-08  11:35:00    body checkup    Generate Prescription Approve Cancel Submit
```

If I click on Approve, it should get disabled and if I click the SUBMIT button (which is the last one in a row), it should show the value of `appointment_id`, `appointment_name` and the value from Approve/Cancel text boxes in the second page. That way I can store it in the database.

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($records, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $result['appointment_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['appointment_username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['appointment_type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $result['message'] . "</td>";
// pass the appointment id and appointment username in url, and access them using $_GET
echo "<td>" . "<a href='prescription.php?app_id=" . $result['appointment_id'] . "&pat_name=" . $result['appointment_username'] . "'>" . 'Generate Prescription' . "</a>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<button type='button' name='b' class='btn btn-success' onclick='this.disabled = true' value='Approved by Doctor'>" . 'Approve' . "</button>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='this.disabled = true' value='Canceled by Doctor'>" . 'Cancel' . "</button>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit2' value='Submit in Database'>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: what should happen if approve is clicked?

Comment: I don't really understand but have you tried using hidden input <input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."> ?

Comment: Is he trying to fetch data from one database and store it in the other?

Comment: What is the exact problem and question here? Please take the time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: I wanted to disable the approve/cancel any button and store their value in Database.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. That's why I don't know the pattern of asking que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your submit button doesn't have a form to submit.
I would change your submit button to a normal button and call a separate function on the page passing the appointment_id to the function.
Also place the appointment_id into the IDs for the approve and cancel buttons.

Then in your new function you can pick up the values of the two buttons and send it to a next page. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
submit_appointment = function(appointment_id){
  var cancelButton = document.getelementById('cancelBtn-' + appointment_id);
  var approveButton = document.getelementById('approveBtn-' + appointment_id);
  var isCancel = (cancelButton.value == 'Canceled by Doctor') ? 'true' : 'false';
  var isApprove = (approveButton.value == 'Approved by Doctor') ? 'true' : 'false';

  document.location.href = 'secondPage.php?appointment_id=' + appointment_id + '&isCancelled=' + isCancel + '&isApproved=' + isApprove;

}
</script>
```

Then you also have to change your buttons to have appointment_id in their IDs. Something like this

```
echo "<td>" . "<button id='cancelBtn-" . $result['appointment_id'] . "' type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='this.disabled = true' value='Canceled by Doctor'>" . 'Cancel' . "</button>" . "</td>";
```

And you'll have to make sure that the onclick for those buttons actually work. I've used the text 'Canceled by Doctor' in the above function, so you'll have to make sure that that condition is actually true when you click one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling the Approve button, use this

```
<button onclick="this.disabled = true">Approved</button>
```

To send the data to the next page, enclose all these input fields within a form tag like

```
<form method="get" action="(link to next page)></form>
```

Be sure to give name to all the input fields

In the next page, use $_GET array to access all the input values, like

```
<input type="number" name="appointment-id" value="<?php echo $_GET['appointment_id'] ?>">
```